# Porque os valores estão se repetindo se não há dados no banco de dados?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

Não estou conseguindo resolver esse problema! Quando faço a frequência dos alunos em um determinado dia, o ****status** deste dia é repetido no mês inteiro**. No exemplo abaixo, fiz do dia 1, depois fiz do dia 2 de um aluno apenas, e observem o que aconteceu.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Verifiquei o página que realiza a frequência e está tudo ok, gravando apenas o dia informado, bem como no banco de dados. O problema está no código abaixo, não encontro onde o script faz a cópia do dia nos dias seguintes.

Código utilizado:

```
<hr />

<?php echo form_open(site_url('admin/attendance_report_selector')); ?>
  <div class="row">
    <?php
    function isWeekend($date) {
      return (date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 7);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get('class');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) :
      $class = $query->result_array();
    ?>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">Ano escolar</label>
        <select class="form-control selectboxit" name="class_id" onchange="select_section(this.value)">
          <option value="">Selecione</option>
          <?php foreach ($class as $row) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['class_id']; ?>" <?php if ($class_id == $row['class_id']) echo 'selected'; ?>><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php
    $query = $this->db->get_where('section', array('class_id' => $class_id));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) :
    $sections = $query->result_array();
  ?>
    <div id="section_holder">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">Turma</label>
          <select class="form-control selectboxit" name="section_id">
            <?php foreach ($sections as $row) : ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row['section_id']; ?>" <?php if ($section_id == $row['section_id']) echo 'selected'; ?>><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">Mês</label>
      <select name="month" class="form-control selectboxit" id="month">
        <?php
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) :
        if ($i == 1) $m = 'Janeiro';
        else if ($i == 2) $m = 'Fevereiro';
        else if ($i == 3) $m = 'Março';
        else if ($i == 4) $m = 'Abril';
        else if ($i == 5) $m = 'Maio';
        else if ($i == 6) $m = 'Junho';
        else if ($i == 7) $m = 'Julho';
        else if ($i == 8) $m = 'Agosto';
        else if ($i == 9) $m = 'Setembro';
        else if ($i == 10) $m = 'Outubro';
        else if ($i == 11) $m = 'Novembro';
        else if ($i == 12) $m = 'Dezembro';
        ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php if ($month == $i) echo 'selected'; ?>>
            <?php echo get_phrase($m); ?>
          </option>
        <?php endfor; ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">Ano letivo</label>
      <select class="form-control selectboxit" name="sessional_year">
        <?php $sessional_year_options = explode('-', $running_year); ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $sessional_year_options[0]; ?>" <?php if ($sessional_year == $sessional_year_options[0]) echo 'selected'; ?>>
          <?php echo $sessional_year_options[0]; ?></option>
        <option value="<?php echo $sessional_year_options[1]; ?>" <?php if ($sessional_year == $sessional_year_options[1]) echo 'selected'; ?>>
          <?php echo $sessional_year_options[1]; ?></option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="year" value="<?php echo $running_year; ?>">

  <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Gerar relatório</button>
  </div>

</div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>

<?php if ($class_id != '' && $section_id != '' && $month != '' && $sessional_year != '') : ?>

  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
      <div class="tile-stats tile-gray">
        <div class="icon"><i class="entypo-docs"></i></div>
        <h3 style="color: #696969;">
          <?php 
          $section_name = $this->db->get_where('section', array('section_id' => $section_id))->row()->name;
          $section_teacher = $this->db->get_where('section', array('section_id' => $section_id))->row()->teacher_id;
          $class_name = $this->db->get_where('class', array('class_id' => $class_id))->row()->name;
          if ($month == 1) $m = 'Janeiro';
          else if ($month == 2) $m = 'Fevereiro';
          else if ($month == 3) $m = 'Março';
          else if ($month == 4) $m = 'Abril';
          else if ($month == 5) $m = 'Maio';
          else if ($month == 6) $m = 'Junho';
          else if ($month == 7) $m = 'Julho';
          else if ($month == 8) $m = 'Agosto';
          else if ($month == 9) $m = 'Setembro';
          else if ($month == 10) $m = 'Outubro';
          else if ($month == 11) $m = 'Novembro';
          else if ($month == 12) $m = 'Dezembro';
          echo get_phrase('Relatório de frequência');
          ?>
        </h3>
        <h4 style="color: #696969;">
          <?php echo get_phrase('') . ' ' . $class_name; ?> : Turma <?php echo $section_name; ?><br>
          <?php echo $m . ' de ' . $sessional_year; ?> <br>
          <?php echo 'Professor(a) ' . $this->db->get_where('teacher', array('teacher_id' => $section_teacher))->row()->name; ?>
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr />

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>#</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
              Alunos <i class="entypo-down-thin"></i> | Dias letivos do mês <i class="entypo-right-thin"></i>
            </td>
            <?php
              $year = explode('-', $running_year);
              $days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $sessional_year);
              // Código que busca o dias letivos no banco de dados
              for ($i = 1; $i <= $days; $i++) {
                    $diasValidos = $this->db->get_where('school_days', array('day' => $i,'month' => $month))->row();
              if (isWeekend($sessional_year . '-' . $month . '-' . $i))
                continue;
              if($diasValidos->day != NULL){
            ?>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <td style="text-align: center;">Faltas</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">F. Acumuladas</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <?php
          $data = array();
          $enrolls = $this->db->get_where('enroll', array('class_id' => $class_id, 'year' => $running_year, 'section_id' => $section_id))->result_array();
          $index = 0;
          $students = [];

          foreach ($enrolls as $enroll) {
            array_push($students, $this->db->get_where('student', array('student_id' => $enroll['student_id']))->row());
            }

          $remStudents = $this->db->get_where('remanejamentos', array(
            'old_class' => $class_id,
            'old_section' => $section_id,
            'year' => $sessional_year,
          ))->result_array();

          foreach ($remStudents as $rem) {
            if (in_array($rem['student_id'], array_column($students, 'student_id')))
              continue;

            array_push($students, $this->db->get_where('student', array('student_id' => $rem['student_id']))->row());
            }

            function orderByName($a, $b) {
              return strcmp($a->name, $b->name);
            }
            usort($students, 'orderByName');

            foreach ($students as $row) :
            $showBlank = false;

            $matriculaData = date('m-Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $row->matricula)));
            $currentData = date('m-Y', strtotime('01' . '-' . $month . '-' . $sessional_year));

            if ($matriculaData > $currentData && explode('-', $matriculaData)[1] == explode('-', $currentData)[1])
              continue;

            if($matriculaData == $currentData)
              $showBlank = true;

              $remanejado = false;

              $rem = $this->db->get_where('remanejamentos', array(
                'student_id' => $row->student_id,
                'old_class' => $class_id,
                'old_section' => $section_id,
              ))->result_array();

              $newStudent = $this->db->get_where('remanejamentos', array(
                'student_id' => $row->student_id,
                'new_class' => $class_id,
                'new_section' => $section_id,
              ))->result_array();

              $dataRem = null;
              $dataRem2 = null;
              $fullDataRem = null;

              if (sizeof($rem) > 0) {
                $remanejado = true;

                $dataRem = date('m-Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $rem[0]['data_remanejado'])));
                $fullDataRem = date('d-m-Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $rem[0]['data_remanejado'])));

                $sectionName = $this->db->get_where('section', array('section_id' => $rem[0]['new_section']))->row()->name;

                if($currentData >= explode('/', $dataRem)[0]){
                  $remName = $row->name . ' - ' .'Rem. p/ Turma ' . $sectionName . ', ' . $rem[0]['data_remanejado'];
                }else{
                  $remName = $row->name;
                }
              }

              if (sizeof($newStudent) > 0) {
                $remanejado = true;

                $sectionName = $this->db->get_where('section', array('section_id' => $newStudent[0]['old_section']))->row()->name;

                $dataRem2 = date('m-Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $newStudent[0]['data_remanejado'])));
                $fullDataRem = date('d-m-Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $newStudent[0]['data_remanejado'])));

                $remName = $row->name . ' - ' .'Rem. Turma ' . $sectionName . ', ' . $newStudent[0]['data_remanejado'];
              }

              $curData = date('m-Y', strtotime($sessional_year . '-' . $month));

              if(($curData < $dataRem && $sessional_year != explode('-', $dataRem)[1]) || ($curData < $dataRem2 && $sessional_year == explode('-', $dataRem2)[1]))
                continue;

            $index++;
            ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?= $index ?></td>
              <td style="text-align: left;">
                <?php
                $transferido = (strlen($row->transferencia) > 1 ? true : false);
                  if ($transferido) {
                    $dataTranferido = $row->transferencia;
                    if(explode('-', $currentData)[0] >= explode('/', $dataTranferido)[1]){
                      $remName = $row->name . ' - ' .'<b> Transferido(a): </b>'.$dataTranferido;
                    }else{
                      $remName = $row->name;
                    }
                  }
                  if ($remanejado || $transferido)
                    echo $remName;
                  else
                    echo $row->name;
                ?>
              </td>
              <?php
                $diasValidos = $this->db->get_where('school_days', array('month' => $month))->result_array();

                $status = 0;
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $days; $i++) {
                  if(in_array($i, array_column($diasValidos, 'day'))){
                  if (isWeekend($sessional_year . '-' . $month . '-' . $i))
                    break;
                    $curDay = $i;
                    if($i < 10)
                      $curDay = '0' . $i;

                    $matriculaData = date('d-m-Y', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $row->matricula)));
                    $currentData = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($curDay . '-' . $month . '-' . $sessional_year));

                    $timestamp != null;
                      $timestamp = strtotime($i . '-' . $month . '-' . $sessional_year);
                      if($timestamp != null) {
                        $attendance = $this->db->get_where('attendance', array(
                          'section_id' => $section_id,
                          'class_id' => $class_id,
                          'year' => $running_year,
                          'timestamp' => $timestamp,
                          'student_id' => $row->student_id
                          ))->result_array();
                        }

                        foreach ($attendance as $row1) :
                          $month_dummy = date('d', $row1['timestamp']);

                          if ($i == $month_dummy){
                            $status = $row1['status'];
                          }
                        endforeach;
              ?>
              <td style="text-align: center; color: white; background: 
                <?php if ($status == 1) {
                  echo "#00a651";
                } 
                if ($status == 2) {
                  echo '#ee4749';
                } 
                ?>;">
                <?php
                  if($status == 1){
                    echo '<i class="fa fa-check"></i>';
                  }
                  if($status == 2){
                    echo '<i class="fa fa-times"></i>';
                  } 
                ?>
              </td>
              <?php }} 
                $attendance = $this->db->get_where('attendance', array(
                  'section_id' => $section_id,
                  'class_id' => $class_id,
                  'year' => $running_year,
                  'student_id' => $row->student_id
                ))->result_array();
              ?>

            <td style="text-align: center;">
              <?php
                $ano = explode('-',$running_year)[0];
                $delimiter = '';
                if($month < 10){
                  $delimiter = 0;
                }
                $timestamp = strtotime($currentData);
                $inicio = strtotime($ano.'-'.$delimiter.$month.'-01T00:00:00.000');
                $aux = 0;
                for($i = 0; $i <= count($attendance); $i++){
                  if($attendance[$i]['status'] == 2 && $attendance[$i]['timestamp'] >= $inicio && $attendance[$i]['timestamp'] <= $timestamp){
                    $aux++;
                  }
                }
                echo $aux;
              ?>
            </td>

            <td style="text-align: center;">
              <?php 
                $timestamp = strtotime($currentData);
                $aux = 0;
                for($i = 0; $i <= count($attendance); $i++){
                  if($attendance[$i]['status'] == 2 && $attendance[$i]['timestamp'] <= $timestamp){
                    $aux++;
                  }
                }
                echo $aux;
              ?>
            </td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </tr>
        <?php ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>

<!-- Tabela Carga Horária -->
<?php
  $hasData = sizeof($this->db->get_where('workload', array('year' => $sessional_year))->result_array()) > 0 ? true : false;
?>
<div class="col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
  <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 5px;">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center">Controle de Carga Horária</th>
          <th class="text-center">Neste Mês</th>
          <th class="text-center">Meses Anteriores</th>
          <th class="text-center">Total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p style="font-weight: 700; text-align: center;">Dias de aulas previstas</p>
          </td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <?php
            if ($hasData) {
              $previstasNesteMes = $this->db->get_where('workload', array(
                'year' => $sessional_year,
                'mes_id' => ($month - 1),
              ))->row()->aulas_previstas;

              echo $previstasNesteMes;
            }
            ?>
          </td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <?php
            if ($hasData) {
              $previstasMesesAnteriores = 0;

              for ($i = 0; $i < ($month - 1); $i++) {
                $previstasMesesAnteriores += $this->db->get_where('workload', array(
                  'year' => $sessional_year,
                  'mes_id' => $i,
                ))->row()->aulas_previstas;
              }

              echo $previstasMesesAnteriores;
            }
            ?>
          </td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <?php
            if ($hasData) {
              echo $previstasMesesAnteriores + $previstasNesteMes;
            }
            ?>
          </td>
        </tr> <!-- ./dias-de-aulas-previstas -->
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p style="font-weight: 700; text-align: center;">Dias de aulas dadas</p>
          </td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <?php
            if ($hasData) {
              $dadasNesteMes = $this->db->get_where('workload', array(
                'year' => $sessional_year,
                'mes_id' => ($month - 1),
              ))->row()->aulas_dadas;

              echo $dadasNesteMes;
            }
            ?>
          </td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <?php
            if ($hasData) {
              $dadasMesesAnteriores = 0;

              for ($i = 0; $i < ($month - 1); $i++) {
                $dadasMesesAnteriores += $this->db->get_where('workload', array(
                  'year' => $sessional_year,
                  'mes_id' => $i,
                ))->row()->aulas_dadas;
              }

              echo $dadasMesesAnteriores;
            }
            ?>
          </td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <?php
            if ($hasData) {
              echo $dadasMesesAnteriores + $dadasNesteMes;
            }
            ?>
          </td>
        </tr> <!-- ./dias-de-aulas-dadas -->
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p style="font-weight: 700; text-align: center;">Dias de aulas a repor</p>
          </td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <?php
            if ($hasData) {
              $reportNesteMes = $this->db->get_where('workload', array(
                'year' => $sessional_year,
                'mes_id' => ($month - 1),
              ))->row()->aulas_report;

              echo $reportNesteMes;
            }
            ?>
          </td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <?php
            if ($hasData) {
              $reportMesesAnteriores = 0;

              for ($i = 0; $i < ($month - 1); $i++) {
                $reportMesesAnteriores += $this->db->get_where('workload', array(
                  'year' => $sessional_year,
                  'mes_id' => $i,
                ))->row()->aulas_report;
              }

              echo $reportMesesAnteriores;
            }
            ?>
          </td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <?php
            if ($hasData) {
              echo $reportMesesAnteriores + $reportNesteMes;
            }
            ?>
          </td>
        </tr> <!-- ./dias-de-aulas-a-report -->
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
<div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; margin-top: 10px;">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Observações</label>
    <textarea rows="6" class="form-control" disabled style="resize: none">
      <?php
        if ($hasData) {
        echo $this->db->get_where('workload_observations', array('year' => $sessional_year, 'mes_id' => ($month - 1),
        'turno' => $this->db->get_where('section', array( 'section_id' => $section_id,))->row()->nick_name))->row()->content;
        }
      ?>
    </textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/attendance_report_print_view/' . $class_id . '/' . $section_id . '/' . $month . '/' . $sessional_year); ?>" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">
          Imprimir relatório
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // ajax form plugin calls at each modal loading,
  $(document).ready(function() {

    // SelectBoxIt Dropdown replacement
    if ($.isFunction($.fn.selectBoxIt)) {
      $("select.selectboxit").each(function(i, el) {
        var $this = $(el),
          opts = {
            showFirstOption: attrDefault($this, 'first-option', true),
            'native': attrDefault($this, 'native', false),
            defaultText: attrDefault($this, 'text', ''),
          };

        $this.addClass('visible');
        $this.selectBoxIt(opts);
      });
    }
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function select_section(class_id) {

    $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/get_section/'); ?>' + class_id,
      success: function(response) {

        jQuery('#section_holder').html(response);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que vi vc só precisa mudar onde esta inicializando a variável $status nessa parte do código

```
<?php
            $diasValidos = $this->db->get_where('school_days', array('month' => $month))->result_array();

            $status = 0;
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $days; $i++) {
              if(in_array($i, array_column($diasValidos, 'day'))){
```

deixa para setar a variavel $status para cada vez que passar no loop, após a linha do for assim:

```
<?php
            $diasValidos = $this->db->get_where('school_days', array('month' => $month))->result_array();

            for ($i = 1; $i <= $days; $i++) {
              $status = 0;
              if(in_array($i, array_column($diasValidos, 'day'))){
```